# In Graphql-relay.js mutation always return TypeError failed to fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, bcrypt, graphql-relay

When i include `bcrypt` to my mutation it is return failed to fetch error.
 No mattter `sync/async`. When I generate hash only for logging , it showing the same error. Why it is acting like that?

```
bcrypt last version. Graphql-relay - 0.5.2
```

Comment: When i open Network tab there is no status and response of request.  Only `Provisional headers are shown` present.

Comment: It seems that all code after bcrypt not reaching. Server instantly cancell request without any error.

Comment: Currentlry i switched to `bcryptjs` package. It works fine.